# presentModalViewController not executing?

Tags: iphone

I'm an experienced software developer (mostly C and C++ in embedded systems, Linux, and Qt for user interfaces).  I've recently made the jump to iPhone development and I've run into a confusing issue with UIViewController and presentModalViewController.  I'm trying to present a modal ABPeoplePickerNavigationController dialog but it's not appearing.

My main application is controlled by an object called Controller, a subclass of NSObject.  I recently added a subclass of UIViewController called AddressBookController (both Controller and AddressBookController are declared in my NIB).

I have this function in Controller which uses an IBOutlet to call a function in AddressBookController (Just a side note, I'm aware that passing 'sender' through is probably not correct--what's the correct way to call a function that's looking for (id)sender as a param?):

```
- (IBAction)addressPressed:(id)sender
{
    [addressViewController showContactPicker:sender];
}
```

Here's my interface declaration for AddressBookViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface AddressBookViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
{
}

@end
```

The showContactPicker function in AddressBookController looks like this:

```
#import "AddressBookViewController.h"

@implementation AddressBookViewController

- (void) showContactPicker:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

...
```

I've verified using the debugger that the [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES] is being called, but nothing appears on the screen and code execution just proceeds to [picker release].  Does anyone have any insight as to why this call isn't doing anything?  I'm not seeing any error messages, warnings, etc. as I run through this code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what nib/xib to use in your init:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
```

Change it to:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName@"ABPeoplePickerNavigationController" bundle:nil];
```

making sure you use whatever your nib file is named, minus the .xib extension.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot but it didn't change anything; it still doesn't display the address book picker.

I only have one .xib file in my project, MainWindow.xib, so I changed the line to this:

     ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];

What does that do?  I read the documentation on initWithNibName but all it says is "Returns a newly initialized view controller with the nib file in the specified bundle."

Thanks again for your help.

Jason

Comment: Sorry to mislead you here. I haven't used the Address Book API and didn't recognize that at first. You shouldn't need to specify the xib when you initialize the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. I put together a sample project and implemented the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and was able to get it to work just fine (http://www.matthew-long.com/download/AddressBook.zip ). Did you implement all of the methods of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate formal protocol?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I'll compare it to my code and try to nail down what's wrong with it.

Comment: The example helped a lot--the problem was in how my application was structured.  My AddressBookViewController wasn't being added as a subview to my main window; it's working now.

Thanks again!